# TI Sensortag, how to use push buttons?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with the new [TI Sensortag](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag/index.shtml?INTC=SensorTag&HQS=sensortag-bt1).
I'm trying to do a simple iOS app that reads the state of those buttons. I've found a lot of guide, tutorial etc. about using Sensortag's sensors (humidity, IR Temperature, ...) but no one talks about push buttons on his top.
Has anyone an idea about them?

Tank you very much

Reda

P.S. I'm using an iPhone 5

Comment: Does it have a characteristic for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0xFFE1 SK_KEY_PRESSED GATT_PERMIT_READ Left/Right Keys, Side key as Bit 2 in test mode only.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/File:BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf

Keys are list on the schematic as "push-button carbon" S2 and S3 and access is through cut-away inserts in the clear plastic cover and via raised bumps (I don't think it's Braille but that would have been a nice touch) in the "lipstick red" case.
Connect via the BLE Device monitor and run in the test mode to see if they are detected as all three switches are checked in this mode and the events are displayed.

Comment: The bumps labeling the buttons are in fact Braille for the letters "T" and "I", respectively.

Comment: Thanks for that update. I did a google and didn't find a match for the bump pattern but I don't know Braille. Adding it is very "Apple-like" -- Little things done very well. The sensor tag is an amazing device.

Comment: Just a note, the "key pressed" UUIDs are not 128-bit like all of the other. Just use "FFE0" and "FFE1", not like the format of the other services or characteristics such as "F0000000-0451-4000-B000-00000000xxxx"

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior (if not reprogrammed) for the side button is:

> When not connected, this button is used to toggle advertising on and off. In pushed when 
>   in a connection, the connection is dropped, sensors reset and all data values are set to zero >(Soft reset).

The hole in the front is not an actual button but an opening for the IR temperature sensor to be able to do remote temperature measurements.

Source: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide

Comment: I know that the hole is not a button, but over the hole there are actually 2 buttons... I was talking about them :p

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at YmsCoreBluetooth, a framework I wrote to build iOS CoreBluetooth apps. I have an example of it working with a TI SensorTag and it supports the push buttons.

http://kickingvegas.github.io/YmsCoreBluetooth/

Comment: Very nice.  My challenge with the buttons on the SensorTag though is that if I (1).depress a button and hold it!  (2).*then* open the app and pair the BLE connection.  (3). the status of the still depressed button is not read.  As I want to use the buttons in a home automation project with a mechanical switch to determine if a door is open or not.