# Detecting the buttons (Simple Keys) on a TI SensorTag in an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, button, sensors

I have a TI SensorTag and want to build an iOS app that recognises when the buttons (The Simple Keys?) are pressed on the SensorTag.

I've written a few apps with Xcode and feel OK with that but don't know where to start with recognising the buttons on the TI SensorTag.

There are loads of example apps out there for all the other sensors (temperature, humidity etc.) but nothing written in the last 12-18 months that talks about the buttons so nothing with storyboards in Xcode.

I just want to know how you would set up a project where I can change something in my app (If I can change some text I can work it out from there) and I don't want to use EvoThings or TechBasic.

Comment: Doesn't the TI SensorTag only have one button?

Comment: In any case, it appears that the code for the iOS app is available from TI after registration: http://www.ti.com/tool/sensortag-sw

Comment: Hi Thomas - Yeh I have the code for the iOS app provided by TI but its far too complex for me and was written in an old version of Xcode so i'm struggling to pick it apart. No storyboards for me to work backwards from.

Comment: I basically just want the code I would need to have one thing on a page change when i press the button on the TI SensorTag.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185803/ti-sensortag-how-to-use-push-buttons) answer your question?

Comment: I'm still no further along with this even after all this time :(

Comment: The link you have shared is just far too complicated for me to understand. I just need a newish xcode project that can receive a click from the left or right button :(

Comment: I asked this earlier, but doesn't the SensorTag only have one button?

Comment: No. It has two buttons on the front at the top. It also has one on the side to turn it on/pair it